# How i can send multiple PUT request with different ITEM_ID

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

i try to change the status of items but need to change the ITEM_ID, i already paused 1 product but i have a csv with all the ITEMS_ID, this is the sample:

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"status":"active"}' https://api.webpage.com/items/MLM12345?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

this change the status for the specific ITEM but i have a csv with all the item_id

```
MLM12346
MLM12347
...ETC
```

How can i use PUT the for loop to make it masive?

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

params = (
    ('access_token', 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN'),
)

data = '{"status":"paused"}'

response = requests.put('https://api.webpage.com/items/MLM12345', headers=headers, 
params=params, data=data)

print(response)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the your `items.csv` looks like:

```
MLM12346
MLM12347
```

you can do the following:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
params = (
    ('access_token', 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN'),
)
data = '{"status":"paused"}'

# read the the lines of the files into a list, each element is an item
with open("items.csv", "r") as f:
    items = f.read().splitlines()

# iterate over the items and inject the item into the url
for item in items:
    response = requests.put(f'https://api.webpage.com/items/{item}', headers=headers,
                            params=params, data=data)

    print(response)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two steps that I see here:

1. Reading the ITEM_ID values from a csv and storing them in a list.

   ```
   #sample code here
   import csv
   import requests
   with open('data.csv', 'rb') as f_input:
       csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
       header = next(csv_input)
       csv_data= zip(*[map(int, row) for row in csv_input])
   ```
2. Looping them over and sending PUT requests to the server

   ```
   items = csv_data[0] #assuming ITEM_ID is the first column
   headers = {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   }

   params = (
       ('access_token', 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN'),
   )

   data = '{"status":"paused"}'
   for item in items:
      response = requests.put('https://api.webpage.com/items/'+item, headers=headers, 
   params=params, data=data)
      print(response+ '\n')
   ```